# Parse specific value from this JSON file with Python?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I'm new to Python and I need some help to parse and insert this specific value from JSON file to CSV file.

Here's a snip of my JSON file

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5555,
            "name": "Dodge RAM",
            "pump": {
                "50400": {
                    "device_id": 50400,
                    "type": "Diesel Car"
                }
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

I want to get CSV output like this

```
id   |    name   | device_id
5555 | Dodge RAM | 50400
```

Here's my Python code:

```
all_rows = response.json()
filename = "output.csv"

with open(filename, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    csv_file.writerow(["id", "name", "device_id"])
    for item in all_rows["data"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['id'], item['name'], item['pump']['device_id'])
```

My code printed all value within pump `"50400": {"device_id": 50400, "type": "Diesel Car"}`
I only want device_id, I don't know how to skip "50400" in pump to get device_id. 50400 is not a constant value, it changes with device_id.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go over the dictionary items and select those whose key equals the 'device_id':

```
[
     [vals['device_id'] for dev_id,vals in item["pump"].items() 
                        if vals['device_id']==int(dev_id)] 
      for item in all_rows["data"]
]
#[[50400]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't understand your answer very much. Could you elaborate? I don't know how your suggestion fit into my code.

Comment: The solution gives you a list of device IDs. Isn't it what you wanted?